# Trouble creating an appropriate xpath

Tags: xpath

Is there any way I can get to the two email addresses using a single xpath? I've tried like below and can't go beyond. At this point, I can locate a single email either using "a/@href" or "/text()" but I expect to have both. Any input on this will be highly appreciated.

Elements within which emails are stored:

```
<div class="_4iw9"><a href="mailto:info@chrisham.com"><div class="_5tz4">info@devlynn.com</div></a></div>
```

I've tried like this:

```
//div[starts-with(@class,"_")]
```

Comment: Would you count `//div[starts-with(@class,"_")]/a/@href | //div[starts-with(@class,"_")]/a/div` as a single XPath expression?

Comment: //div[starts-with(@class,"_")]/a/@href | //div[starts-with(@class,"_")]/text() gives me both. Thanks sir, for your answer. Would you please give this answer in such a way so that i can accept it.